# Dart and Flutter for loop multiple iterators

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, for-loop

I have a for loop in my Flutter project similar to this (simplified):

`for(int i=0; i<aVariableDeclaredBefore; i++) Padding(....`

Here I need another operation after i++ run as this one **anotherVariable--**. I can't do it in {} braces because loop used for Widget manipulation. There is no curly braces there.

I need something like this `((i++)&&(anotherVariable--))` but how ? if it is possible

Comment: Alternatively consider if you need `anotherVariable` at all.  If you're always incrementing `i` and always decrementing `anotherVariable`, on each iteration you could derive the intended value for `anotherVariable` from `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the comma <strike>operator</strike>:

```dart
void main() {
  for (var i = 0, j = 10; i < 10; i++, j++) {
    print('i=$i, j=$j');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
i=0, j=10
i=1, j=11
i=2, j=12
i=3, j=13
i=4, j=14
i=5, j=15
i=6, j=16
i=7, j=17
i=8, j=18
i=9, j=19
```

Comment: You wrote: `Use the comma operator`. You're not right. The comma is not an operator. This is the expression separator in the list of expressions. You shouldn't mislead people. Dart does not and never will have the `,` operator.